# Multi HTML pages in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile

Recently I started using jQuery Mobile for a native android app (with phoneGap).

This is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>


    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="all_app_position" data-role="homePage">
    <div data-role="header" class="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        Middle contnet
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        footer content
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to import content (below) from a second html file into the middle div.

```
     <div data-role="page" id="about">
         <div data-role="header"><h1>Page 2</h1></div>
         <div data-role="content"><p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p></div>
         <div data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div>
     </div>
```

how can i do it?!
I tried a lot of ways and I couldn't.

Important to me that the link will be using Ajax.

Sorry about my English

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to embed an html from different file. Please check the link http://webdesign.about.com/od/ssi/a/aa052002a.htm for more information.

One of the best methods is inline frames or iframe tags in HTML.

Comment: Is JQM don't includes a function that replaces pages within a specific DIV?!